# Not able to find sun.awt.image.codec package

Tags: java

I searched a good lot but all in vain.
I want to get the source for sun.awt.image.codec.* java package.

Any help will be very appreciated..

Thanks

**EDIT**
Actually I have to use that package only, its required for my work. Its necessary for me since I am doing a performance eval [i can't change the code].

Comment: May I ask why you need to source of that package? If you're just looking for loading and/or writing images, use the standard [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)'s `read()` and `write()` methods.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Comment: Actually I have to use that package only, its required for my work. Its necessary for me since I am doing a performance eval [i can't change the code]

Answer (score 1):

Update: This code is proprietary and the sources aren't available.

Try to use a decompiler or write black box performance tests.

Comment: Is it possible to get the jar at least?

Comment: The package sun.awt.image.codec.* is included in the rt.jar from Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use OpenJDK? Install oracle jdk and try then.

Comment: Does the oracle JDK have that package?

Comment: Some version should have, because sun.awt, as name says, is package of Sun, which was bought by Oracle. Try 6 and 7 versions of jre

Comment: Tried it on my computer. 1.6.0_24 has this package.